# Traceroute using UDP instead of ICMP?

Tags: networking, firewall, ping, udp, traceroute

I am playing a game named "Planetside 2" and since a few days many users including me have high ping issues on a specific server, while others have not.

Therefore I wanted to try to traceroute / ping the Server IP, to find out which server node causes the high ping issues.

However it seems like the Server has some kind of Firewall that protects itself from being pinged by ICMP. Whenever I use "ping 69.174.216.23" (the ip is public on google so I can share it here) I get a timeout response.

So I used Wireshark to find out how the Game Client communicates with the Server and I found out that it's using UDP to ping the Server IP:Port.

However the Server has only a few Ports open for example for the Server IP: 69.174.216.23
The following ports are the only ones that it communicates with:
{ 20112, 20113, 20143, 20156, 20157, 20164, 20168, 20175 }

If I simulate that, sending a 1Byte UDP Packet to the Server it does not work, but if I add one of the Ports behind it 69.174.216.23:20112 and send a 1Byte UDP Packet I get a response.

I made a simple python script like that which works fine for that purpose:

```
import socket
import time

def udp_ping(destination_ip, destination_port):
    try:
        # Create a UDP socket
        udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        
        # Set a timeout for receiving responses (in seconds)
        udp_socket.settimeout(5)
        
        # Record the time just before sending the message
        start_time = time.time()
        
        # Send a message to the destination
        udp_socket.sendto(b'PONG', (destination_ip, destination_port))
        
        # Receive a response
        response, address = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        
        # Record the time when the response is received
        end_time = time.time()
        
        # Calculate round-trip time (RTT) in milliseconds
        rtt_ms = (end_time - start_time) * 1000
        
        print("Received response from {}: {} (RTT: {:.2f} ms)".format(address, response.decode(), rtt_ms))
    
    except socket.timeout:
        print("No response received.")

    finally:
        udp_socket.close()

destination_ip = '69.174.216.23'
destination_port = 20112 
udp_ping(destination_ip, destination_port)
```

So since I am not able to traceroute or ping the Server IP using ICMP, I wonder if there is another possible way, like using an approach like I did with udp ip:port instead?

I searched around a bit and found out that you can udp traceroute but that uses its probe on UDP port number 33434 and since the Targets Server IP only listens / responds to a few ports (20112, 20113, 20143, 20156, 20157, 20164, 20168, 20175).

So I tried it this way:

```
using (UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient())
{
    udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;

    for (short ttl = 1; ttl <= maxHops; ttl++)
    {
        string message = $"Traceroute[{ttl}]: ";

        // Set the TTL option for the UDP socket
        udpClient.Client.Ttl = ttl;

        // Send a UDP packet to the target
        udpClient.Send(new byte[1], 1, targetIp, targetPort);

        message += $"UDP packet sent to {targetIp}:{targetPort}";

        try
        {
            // Receive response from the target or an intermediate router
            UdpReceiveResult result = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();

            IPAddress senderIp = result.RemoteEndPoint.Address;

            if (senderIp.Equals(targetIp))
            {
                targetReached = true;
                message += " - Target reached";
            }
            else
            {
                message += $" - Received response from {senderIp}";
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
            {
                message += " - Timeout";
            }
            else
            {
                message += $" - Error: {ex.Message}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message += $" - Error: {ex.Message}";
        }

        if (targetReached)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However here the issue is that as soon as i set `udpClient.Client.Ttl = ttl;` it doesn't get any anymore here `UdpReceiveResult result = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();` but if I comment the TTL out it works fine.

So now I am stuck and wonder if there is another possible way to traceroute the IP?

Doesn't matter which enviroment, linux, c#, python, powershell im fine with that, just to get an idea.

Comment: *"you can udp traceroute but that uses its probe on UDP port number 33434"* - no idea where this comes from. Usually the destination port can be configured. For example see option `-p` in [traceroute](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich alright, I updated my question above and using the code I don't get any response with TTL enabled. Is there another possible method?

Comment: Since it *"Doesn't matter which enviroment, linux, c#, python, powershell"* just use traceroute, which already provides what you want to achieve. See my last comment.

Comment: Traceroute, which is an ancient Unix command-line tool, traditionally uses UDP datagrams with small TTLs and watches for ICMP "destination unreachable: time exceeded" messages to come back. The port doesn't matter most of the time because most of the UDP datagrams are not expected to reach the target host.

Apparently when Microsoft created the "tracert" command-line tool as a reimplementation of Unix traceroute for MS-DOS or Windows, they decided to use ICMP echoes instead of UDP datagrams, and in my opinion that was always a poor choice. All non-Microsoft OSes do UDP traceroute by default.

Comment: @Spiff thanks for your comments, I tried out linux traceroute and with the "traceroute -U -p port ip" command I was able to trace it perfectly. Now I wonder how would I have to recode my code above, so that I can get the IP of each node? Because I always get a "SocketException / AggregateException: Connection interrupted because of Keep-Alive smth."

Answer (score 1):

Traceroute probes do not require the server to have anything open, as their purpose is to trigger replies from the *intermediate* routers, not from the final host; they never actually reach the final host. The actual type of the probe doesn't matter; all of them result in the same kind of reply.

But even if the probe was UDP, the reply of traceroute probes is not a UDP packet and won't be delivered through Receive() – instead, you always get an ICMP `TTL Exceeded` **error** packet, which might be reported as an exception or might require some special socket option.

(The only exception to the above is the "final" probe which has a large enough TTL that it actually reaches the host. If the host doesn't respond, then the trace will hang at that point, but you should have timeouts for that situation because intermediate routers *also* are allowed to not respond.)

Comment: Hey I tried out linux traceroute and with the "traceroute -U -p port ip" command I was able to trace it perfectly. Now I wonder how would I have to recode my code above, so that I can get the IP of each node? Because I always get a "SocketException / AggregateException: Connection interrupted because of Keep-Alive smth."